Is it possible to improve the efficiency of modeling work by executing Java program code?
Is it possible to execute Java program code to automatically
accomplish the manual process of opening the palette, dragging
the required elements onto the main diagram, and connecting the elements?
I am a beginner in Anylogic, so I would appreciate your guidance.
I want to create a mechanism to easily generate a simulation model by simply importing a flowchart of the work.

Check this webinar. Totally possible but not trivial and you do need a considerable amount of experience: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=casVdmKC-S0&t=1s

Absolutely!  However, it may or may not be more efficient.  Instead of thinking about dragging the pallet agents/objects over to the canvas, think about creating your generic structure on the canvas and then parameterizing by increasing the agents in the population, connecting ports at runtime, etc.
We create flexible/generic structures with almost all projects, but you really need to define your use case.  If you want something to be generic for any project EVER, then the AnyLogic development environment is that use case.  If you have a particular system (i.e., I work in a hospital and I want my lean engineers to take their Visio flowcharts and simulate them), then you should architect to that system.
What you are describing is advanced, so I would start small, with a well-defined problem.
